# PHP Get wrong info by email from html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Live Form- http://www.arif-khan.net/project/cform/main/index-4.html

I add javascript validation there, everything work perfectly except i get wrong value on Contact Number section on email(check contact number from email body). I add javascript  validation there so user must need to put numeric value on that field.

```
<input type="text" id="abc1" name="contact1"/> <input type="text" id="abc1" name="contact2"/> <input type="text" id="abc1" name="contact3"/> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["contact1"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="" || (/[^0-9]/.test( x )))
    {
        alert("Contact Number must be filled out/Not a valid Contact Number");
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["contact2"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="" || (/[^0-9]/.test( x )))
    {
        alert("Contact Number must be filled out/Not a valid Contact Number");
        return false;
    }

    var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["contact3"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="" || (/[^0-9]/.test( x )))
    {
        alert("Contact Number must be filled out/Not a valid Contact Number");
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

These are the emails that I am getting from the contact form.

```
Brian, Someone Sent you a Contact Message through your Website.

                Details Below-
                Name: Owen Owen
                Email Address: kidrock@msn.com
                Contact Number: kidrock@msn.com kidrock@msn.com kidrock@msn.com
                Zip Code: 65961
                Best Time To Contact: Afternoon
                Payment Plan Options: PLAN TWO - $150/For 2 Hrs ($60/Bi-Wk Payment Plan) Incl's MUA/Unlimited Images
                MUA: No
                Shoot Concept:
                Shoot Concept(Other): NhkiperljgjvJKpjT
```

How do I get this to stop or what can be done to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this lines in your code.

**from**

```
if (x==null || x=="" || (/[^0-9]/.test( x )))
```

**to**

```
if (x==null || x=="" || ! (/[^0-9]/.test( x )))
```

Look at the **>> ! <<** mark.

Comment: Contact field is fully validated, but i get wrong info by email.

Comment: It **can't** be valid this way. Your code only throws an error when the Contact-Number is **valid**.